# PowerShell - extracting text into variables (RegEx?)

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a PS script that pulls some status information from a switch. The output looks like this:

```
     8    Auto       Unknown        -1  Class 4      On     Good      3.29       47.75        68.96
```

I now need to assign these strings to variables, for further processing. I'm guessing RegEx would be the best (only?) way to do it, but I don't have the first clue on how to achieve that, so any suggestion will be gratefully received.

Cheers,

B.

Comment: Is output object or plaint text?

Comment: The text is stream return from an SSH command. The stream is assigned to a variable, which I ran through a write-host, just to create the sample when asking the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the fields seem to be **separated by varying numbers of spaces**, it is simplest to **use the unary form of `-split`**, the [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split):

```
# Sample input.
$line = @'
     8    Auto       Unknown        -1  Class 4      On     Good      3.29       47.75        68.96
'@

# Split the line into an array of fields by whitespace.
$fields = -split $line

# Output the result.
$fields
```

If you additionally want to ***infer the data types* of the fields**, simply by seeing if they can be converted to an integer (`[int]`) or a floating-point value (`[double]`):

```
foreach ($i in 0..($fields.Count-1)) {
  if ($newValue = $fields[$i] -as [double]) { $fields[$i] = $newValue }
  if ($newValue = $fields[$i] -as [int])    { $fields[$i] = $newValue }
}
```